# How to serve generated Vue app from Laravel route?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have not a default setup vue + laravel, vue completely separately from laravel.
In my case laravel only as API. I finished doing a vue app and did a `build` command for production.

I got the generated resources in this form:

[image]

I was thinking about how to upload to the hosting such an application and came to the conclusion that i need to send vue files through my laravel server.

I wrote route in **routes/web.php**:

```php
Route::get('{uri}', function ($uri = '/') {
    $sourceByUri = public_path('_frontend/' . $uri);

    if (is_file($sourceByUri)) {
        return file_get_contents($sourceByUri);
    }

    $indexSpa = public_path('/_frontend/index.html');

    return file_get_contents($indexSpa);
})->where('uri', '.*');
```

My api works as it should, but the files from the folder _frontend are not sent correctly(css not applicable). [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Otbsy.png)

Should be like this: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9lak.png)

It turned out that all responses from the server are worth `Content-Type: text/html`

**How do I properly open my application through a server?**

Comment: Your css and js files would need to be accessible from the same path.  I assume you aren't prefixing _frontend when referencing them in index.html.

Comment: All files come with a code 200, and the scripts work, the problem is that everywhere `Content-Type: text/html`, I tried changing `Content-Type` to `text/css` and it all worked, but at the same time all responses with `text/css`(html, css, other files). [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/1WbhzkX.png)

Comment: I tried to get a mime type: `mime_content_type($sourceByUri)` but for css and js it returns `text/plain`

Comment: Ah, i just noticed your code attempts to serve all files, not just index.html.  That's probably a bad idea, it'd be much slower to serve files through php/laravel versus a web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should serve your front-end app directly through Nginx and configure a reverse proxy to access the API through Laravel:

First, configure your laravel app so that Nginx can serve it (I made Nginx listen on a random port for this configuration):

```
server {
    listen 1222;

    root /var/www/html/your-app/public;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Insert PHP configs here etc...
}
```

Then, serve your webapp and make calls that are going to the `/api` endpoint go to your laravel app instead of your front-end app. Make it listen on port 80 if you want to serve through http or 443 if you want it to be served through https:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your-app.com;

    root /var/www/your-app/public/_frontend;

    location /api {
        # Backend server to forward requests to/from
        proxy_pass          http://localhost:1222;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        client_max_body_size 500M;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will deal with this. I googled a lot and could not find a solution to my problem, It looks like this rare approach. Thanks again, I thought no one would help me.

Comment: No problem. I think however that the best is to divide completely the two projects. They are not meant to live in the same git repository for example. You could have different `.env` files for your projects etc... Dividing completely helps to think how to deal with those problems. You have two applications, one server side application and one client side application

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if I divide so, do I have to pay for both hosting at the same time? I know that there are free static hosting for vue, but there is a limit on the number of sites.

Comment: mmm I don't know, I use VPS so you can configure unlimited websites on it

Comment: ok, I'm just a beginner programmer, not yet experience with vps. I had an idea how to solve my problem, see my answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

From [this example](https://github.com/iliyaZelenko/laravel-vue-cli-3), i understood how to combine Vue CLI with Laravel.